# How to get `csrftoken` in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, js-cookie

In Vue.js project, how can I get the `csrftoken`?

I tried use `js-cookie`, but can not get it:

```
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

if (Cookies.get('csrftoken')!==undefined) {   // there will skip, because the Cookies.get('csrftoken') is undefined.

  config.headers['x-csrftoken']= Cookies.get('csrftoken');  // 'CSRFToken '

}
```

but I can get other cookie.

---

**EDIT**

```
Cookies.get('csrftoken')
```

this code get `undefined`.

But when I access, there is the `csrftoken`.

[image]

Comment: I use the debugger, in there , I console the `document.cookie`, there is no `csrftoken` and `sessionid`, when I request a api, they will appear in the Cookie in the request header.

Answer (score 1):

```
Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = document.querySelector('#token').getAttribute('value');
```

get csrf from cookies:

```
 function getCookie(name)
  {
    var re = new RegExp(name + "=([^;]+)");
    var value = re.exec(document.cookie);
    return (value != null) ? unescape(value[1]) : null;
  }
```

Comment: `#token`? I want to get the `csrftoken`. should change it to this?

Comment: you can get cookies with *document.cookie*. i hope this helps!

Comment: I am not sure whether the js-cookie store the cookie data in the document.cookie.

Comment: What if the cookie is `http-only`?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to simply print it in the DOM on the server level. The get it from there. Laravel is a good example:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/csrf#csrf-x-xsrf-token

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Of course replace `{{ csrf_token() }}` with your server language and the CSRF token.

And in your JS:

```
config.headers['x-csrftoken']=  $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
```

If using jQuery.

Comment: it says save the `csrftoken` in the `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">` tag. but I use the Vue.js as the frontend. can I write like this?

Comment: so it's only in the Cookies, nowhere else? Sorry though the page was server generated in the first place and you were looking to get it on the JS side.

Comment: Try to console.log(Cookies.get('csrftoken')) or the Cookie object to get the right key.

Comment: Ohh, the `Cookies.get('csrftoken')` can not get the csrftoken.